# MATLAB: fir1 command is incompatible fir2 command

Tags: matlab, filter, coefficients

MATLAB said "The fir2 function also designs windowed FIR filters, but with an arbitrarily shaped piecewise linear frequency response. 
This is in contrast to fir1, which only designs filters in standard lowpass, highpass, bandpass, and bandstop configurations."

I found fir filter coefficients with fir1 command  and get frequency responses by using freqz as follows

```
b1=fir1(M,wn,'high') % b1:highpass FIR filter coefficients

hd=freqz(b1,1,w) %FIR filter frequency responses with respect to b1
```

then I pass this frequency responses(hd) to fir2 as follows

```
b2=fir2(M,w,hd) % get FIR filter coefficient from same frequency samples(w) and frequency responses(hd)
```

b1 must equal to b2 according to MATLAB
but  for the FIR filter of order 13
this is the result :

b1=0.0042    0.0063   -0.0000   -0.0403   -0.1221   -0.2103    0.7470   -0.2103   -0.1221   -0.0403   -0.0000 0.0063    0.0042

b2=0.0017   -0.0044    0.0180   -0.0937    0.2075   -0.1097   -0.0012    0.0105   -0.0081    0.0050   -0.0025  0.0010   -0.0005

b1 isn't equal to b2.This is supposed to be right in theory.I don't understand what's wrong.